# Recovering Ubuntu 9.10 /Windows 7 dual boot with Wubi

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7, ubuntu-9.10, boot

I had installed Ubuntu 9.10 /Windows 7 dual boot with Wubi.  I had no issues for about 9 months, and then after having to do a force reboot after ubuntu got hunng, and never goes past boot-up.

On boot up, and selecting ubuntu, I get this error message:

`One or more of the mounts listed in /etc/fstab cannot yet be mounted:

/: waiting for /dev/loop0 

/tmp: waiting for (null) 

Press ESC to enter a recovery shell`

When I enter the recovery shell, I get this error message: 

`General error mounting filesystem 

A maintainance shell will be started`

The maintenace shell does start- and I am able to access files.  However, X-server does not work, so gedit, and similar applications does not work.
I have done chkdsk on Windows, and this didnt solve nmy problem. 
From what I have been reading online,I have seen quite a few posts advising against wubi ubuntu installation, and generally to the  effect that 'do a clean install'  
I found  that the person on this thread has faced an identical issue, but he had to do a re-install  

`http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1051277.html`

Can I make my ubuntu box work right, as it was before?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the force-reboot caused some corruption to your linux filesystem, which is preventing it from booting.

The windows chkdsk will only fix problems with the Windows NTFS filesystem, not the ext4 filesystem that Ubuntu uses.

You will need to run fsck utility from the recovery shell to repair errors and hope it can repair the damage.